# Command to create \begin{} \end{} environment in LaTeX

Tags: text-generation

How can I make a command that allows me to insert LaTeX environments in the current text?

The idea is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or type `:texenv` and then enter the environment name in the bottom line, e.g. `:texenv itemize`. Which would then insert a

```
\begin{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Ideally placing the curser after the begin's closing brace.

I suspect I could do this with `command` but how do I paste the text into the buffer?

Comment: If you're using Vim-LaTeX/LaTeX-Squite, press F5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple function to insert text with the [`append()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#append%28%29) function:

```
fun! TexEnv(name)
        let l:l = line(".") - 1
        call append(l:l, "\\end{" . a:name . "}")
        call append(l:l, "\\begin{" . a:name . "}")
endfun
```

You can then use `command` to call this; with `-nargs=1` we tell it to require one argument, and we pass this to our function with `<args>`:

```
command! -nargs=1 Texenv call TexEnv("<args>")
```

Custom commands have to start with an upper case, so I've named it `Texenv`.

We can use the same function with a key mapping; the [`input()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#input%28%29) function asks you for your TeX environment name, and passes that on to the `TexEnv()` function:

```
nnoremap <C-e> :call TexEnv(input("TeX environment name: "))<CR>
```

Note that `<C-e>` is already bound to scrolling the screen (which is rather useful IMHO), so you're overwriting that mapping...

Comment: Brilliant. `fun! TexEnv(name)
  call append(line("."), "\\end{" . a:name . "}")
  call append(line(".")-1, "\\begin{" . a:name . "}")
endfun` seems to do exactly what I was looking for! And I will probably keep it at `:Texenv`.

Answer (score 1):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.

#### Example

For *snipMate*, your snippet would look like this; it would be triggered by typing `texenv<Tab>`:

```
snippet texenv
    \begin{${1:environment-name}}
    \end{$1}$2
```

Comment: I installed `snipMate` but although it works in c files, the default snips (that already contain a begin snippet) don't load in `.tex` files.

Comment: Verify that the `'filetype'` corresponds to the snippet file: `:setl filetype?`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround). For example add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/latex.vim`

```
let b:surround_{char2nr('e')} = "\\begin{\1environment: \1}\r\\end{\1\1}"
```

Now you can do `<c-s>b` in insert mode to add the surrounding. You can also surround text with other surround operators like `ys`, `yS` and `v_S`.

For more help see:

```
:h surround
:h surround-customizing
```