# Automaticall close LaTeX begin environment with end

Tags: vimscript, neovim, filetype-tex

I want to automate some routine operations when working with LaTeX documents writing, e.g. I often write these lines:

```tex
\begin{<environment-name>}
some text and commands here
\end{<environment-name>}
```

Where `<environment-name>` is different environments (e.g. `enumerate`, `description`, and many others).

When I start `\begin{<environment-name>}`, I want to make vim (neovim) automatically add `\end{<environment-name>}` at the next line and return the cursor back, right after `\begin{<environment-name>}`. What vim script I can use to automate it?

I already checked [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2170/9140) but it doesn't work for me, since it's about new command, not auto insertion of text.

Comment: You can do this with surround.vim (endwise doesnt have it out of the box, but it might be able to handle it)

Comment: With [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/), you can close the environment with the insert mode mapping `]]`.

Comment: [ultisnip](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) is what you want.